# If $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence prove that $f \in C^{o}(D) $ iff $x_{n} \rightarrow l$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ (Continuous extension)

Tags: analysis, limits

If $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence and $l \in \mathbb{R}$; let D:={$\frac{1}{n}|n\in\mathbb{N}$} $\cup$ {0} and define:

$f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $x\mapsto f(x)$ := { $l$ if $x$=0 and 
                                               {$x_{n}$ if $\frac{1}{x}=n \in \mathbb{N}$

Prove that $f \in C^{o}(D) $ iff $x_{n} \rightarrow l$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

I'm fairly certain that this question is about continuous extensions but I don't know how to go about the proof. I think I should be thinking about isolated parts of the domain and using the definition of limits and continuity. I'm just unsure as to how to translate this as a proof.

Comment: its not that much abend continuous extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the definition of a continuous function, a function is continous if 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } f(x_n) = f(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n)$$
If $x_n \not \to l$ than $f$ is not continous in $0$, as 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(\frac{1}{n})=\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n
 \neq f(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\frac{1}{n}))=f(0)=l$$
When $x_n\to l$ than 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)= l = f(\lim_{x\to 0} x) =f(0)=l$$

for $x_0\neq 0$ the point is isolated and hence the function is contniuous in it.
To prove this one use the epsilon delta definiton and chose $\delta$ so small that the only point of your neighborhood is $x_0$.

Comment: Could you expand a little?

Comment: @Mathlete A continuous function will satisfy $f(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(\frac{1}{n})$. What does this tell you about $l$ and $x_n$?

Comment: I realised I made a mistake on the question. It should be $\frac{1}{x}$ My apologies. Does this change anything?

Comment: I dont think so, the function $f$ just assigns to $\frac{1}{n}$ the element $x_n$

Comment: Alright. I'm still not getting what it tells you about $l$ and $x_{n}$

Comment: Can you identify $f(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n})$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(\frac{1}{n})$?

Comment: @Mathlete ok I expanded it

Comment: The former would be f(0) which is $l$ and the latter, $lim x_{n}$ which must be $l$ by definition of a continuous function. I understand now!